# Is there any way to work with Twitter API in a frontend web application?

Tags: javascript, twitter, jsonp

I am developing a little app that is supposed to utilize Twitter Search API. You can only search tweets if you're authenticated. So I tried a [js library](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient) (I am using webpack) that is recommended by Twitter as a JavaScript library for their API. I thought it would work on the front end, but it doesn't, because it uses an OAuth implementation that doesn't appear to support JSONP.

Is there a way to work with the Twitter API from the client-side? Maybe a better library? Or should I just move tweet search functionality to the back end? I've heard you need to include an 'Authorization' header for twitter API requests, and so far I am unaware of a way to inject headers into a JSONP request.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript

Comment: Great suggestion. Except for the part that you should've read through the question more carefully; I don't just need to **display** some tweets, I need to actually **fetch** them.

Answer (score -4):

1. You should start with [Getting Started With the Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/getting-started) and read it thoroughly.  This will help you make an informed decision about which tools to use and how to architect your application.
2. All calls to the Twitter API must be authenticated.
3. Whatever you do, don't write your own OAuth code.  There are plenty of OAuth libraries already available for free that work.  Writing your own OAuth mechanism is pain.